# Algorithm to generate all independent sets of an undirected graph?

Tags: graph-theory, independent-set

We need an algorithm to generate all independent sets of an undirected graph.

For example:

[image]

We tried to use ['Bron-Kerbosch'](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24591) algorithm, but do not understand how to interpret the result.

**Input:**

A = [1 2; 1 5; 2 3; 2 5; 3 4; 4 5; 4 6]

**Desired Output:**

B = [1 3 6; 1 4; 2 4; 2 6; 3 5 6]

How to interpret the result?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just realised how to solve it....

**Input:**

A = [1 2; 2 3; 3 4; 4 5; 4 6]

Convert to adjacency matrix:

```
 0     1     0     0     1     0
 1     0     1     0     1     0
 0     1     0     1     0     0
 0     0     1     0     1     1
 1     1     0     1     0     0
 0     0     0     1     0     0
```

**BK_MaxIS Output:**

```
 1     1     0     0     0
 0     0     1     1     0
 1     0     0     0     1
 0     1     1     0     0
 0     0     0     0     1
 1     0     0     1     1
```

Where row i of column j is 1, the vertex i participates in the maximal independent set indexed by column j.

**That means:**

B = [1 3 6; 1 4; 2 4; 2 6; 3 5 6]